# left outer join in R

Tags: r, join, merge

I am trying to perform a left outer join on two data frames in R and I get some weird behavior. The first data frame (a) contains 509100 elements (rows) and the second one (b) contains 325020 rows. The function I have used for the left outer join is the following:

```
merge(a, b, by=c("ID","SEQUENCE"), all.x = T, all.y = F)
```

The resulting data frame now contains 513248 rows. I have used the same method with the same parameter configuration earlier in the script and it worked fine (i.e., the resulting data frame had the same number of rows as the first data frame passed as argument in the merge function). I have also created a column in each of the two data frames, as a combination of ID_SEQUENCE (at character level, for instance ID = 345 and SEQUENCE = 4, then the resulting value is 345_4) in order to avoid merging on multiple columns, if that would raise a problem, but the result is the same... 513248 rows instead of the expected 509100. Any ideas why this is happening or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most likely your ID/SEQUENCE combinations are not unique in one of the tables.  Check with `nrow(unique(a[,c("ID","SEQUENCE")]))` or `duplicated`

Comment: `df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:5,y = letters[1:5]); df2 <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,2:5)); merge(df1,df2,all.x = TRUE)`. Your problem is duplicates key values, you just haven't recognized where they are yet.

Comment: OK. I will look into it in more detail. Thank you both for your help.